# filter rendered elements in react using select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make this app, it's a simple react app with google books API. My question is how can I filter rendered elements depending on select value? I've tried useEffect and .filter method but I just can't figure it out. Here's what I got so far:

```
function App() {

  const[book, setBook] = useState("");
  const[result, setResult] = useState([]);
  const[apiKey, setApiKey] = useState("MY API KEY");

  const[sortBy, setSortBy]= useState("relevance")

  const [categorie, SetCategorie]= useState("all")
  
  function handleChange(event){
    const book = event.target.value;
    setBook(book)
  };

  function handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    axios.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+book+"&key="+apiKey+"&maxResults=30&orderBy="+sortBy)
.then(function(res){
  setResult(res.data.items)
     console.log(res.data.items)
})
  };
```

And that's when the problem starts

```
  useEffect(function(){

    result.filter(function(book){
    const filteredBooks =  
    book.volumeInfo.categories.includes(categorie)
      console.log(book)
    
    })
    
  },[categorie])

  return (
    <div className="container mt-4 ">
    <h1>Search for books API</h1>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
          <div className="form-group ">
            <input onChange={handleChange} 
            type="text" className="form-control " 
            autoComplete="off" 
            placeholder="enter book name">
            </input>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success"> Search now</button>

          <select onChange={function(event){
            let selectedSortBy = event.target.value;
            setSortBy(selectedSortBy)
            
          }}>
```

I've also needed to change API requests with select values, but that bit seems to work fine

```
            <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
            <option value="newest">Newest</option>
          </select>

        </form>

          <select onChange = {function(event){
              let selectedCategorie = event.target.value;
              SetCategorie(selectedCategorie);
              
          }}>
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="Art">Art</option>
            <option value="Biography">Biography</option>
            <option value="Computers">Computers</option>
            <option value="History">History</option>
            <option value="Medical">Medical</option>
            <option value="Poetry">Poetry</option>
          </select>

          
          <div class="row">
       {result.map(book => {
         
        return <div class="col">
        <div class="box">
        <Card 
            img = {book.volumeInfo.imageLinks === undefined
        ? ""
        : `${book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}`}
            category = {book.volumeInfo.categories}
            title = {book.volumeInfo.title}
            authors = {book.volumeInfo.authors}
          />
        </div>
     </div>
      })}
       </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Suggestion, tidy your code and repost it in one block - don't add comments like that in the middle of it - it's hard to read

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have select component which contains book categories list and once user changes the category you wish to show books only with selected categories.

```
const onCategoryChange = (event) => {
   const selectedCategory = event.target.value;
   const filteredBooks = result.filter((book) => 
    book.volumeInfo.categories.includes(selectedCategory));
    setCategories(selectedCategory);
    setResult(filteredBooks);
   };
<select onChange = {onCategoryChange}>
```

1. Get all categories
2. Filter out the books using the categories
3. Set categories and books.

Comment: thank you very much, the logic work i guess, it makes sense. But it kept giving me error: "cannot read property 'includes' of undefined". I think it's because some of the books have no category and value is undefined. Anyway i just found another query parameter in google books documentation, which is subject: category,   and that made things so much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Im not too familiar with react hooks, however if I understand correctly the function runs every time the `category` variable changes. The filter method needs to return `truish` value if you want to keep an item and `falseish` if not. It creates a new array which is returned. In your case you only set a const and log a value, returning void (implicit).

This should update the result to match your filtered books.

```js
  useEffect(function(){

    result = result.filter(function(book){
        const includesCategory = book
            .volumeInfo
            .categories
            .includes(categorie);
            console.log(book)
        return includesCategory;
    })
    
  },[categorie])
```